# Count html elements and divide by 100

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have the following simple nav on a page.

```css
.tab-nav a,
.tab-nav a:visited,
.tab-nav a:focus,
.tab-nav a:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
}
```

```html
<nav class="tab-nav">   
  <a>Item One</a>
  <a>Item Two</a>
  <a>Item Three</a>
  <a>Item Four</a>
  <a>Item Five</a>
</nav>
```

Is it possible to count the `<a>` elements (in this case 5) and divide by 100?

To give you some context, this nav is used on a content carousel ([Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/)) within WordPress. Each page will have a different number of nav elements. [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) uses absolute positioning, so I need to divide the `<a>` elements to fit 100% width. Flexbox is not compatible with [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/) which is why I need to go down the absolute positioning route.

In my example, the calculation would equal 20. This calculation would then be used to apply a width. E.g. `<a style="width: 20%">`.

Comment: Why don't you use jquery?

Comment: At the moment, the site doesn't depend on any JQuery, so it would be cool if I could keep it that way.

Comment: You can also use simple javascript

Comment: Client-side should 100% be kept client-side, but PHP does have a DOM parser that you can researc

Comment: I've edited my question as I'm open to solutions outside of PHP.

Comment: Can you explain what _“this nav is used on a content carousel”_ actually means? As content in one of the slides? As bullet navigation? Something completely different? _“Flexbox is not compatible with Flickity which is why I need to go down the absolute positioning route.”_ - before you properly explain what you are actually trying to do here, I wouldn’t see that as a given.

Comment: Also, if you don’t need this for ridiculous numbers of possible links, but just for a manageable amount - https://alistapart.com/article/quantity-queries-for-css/

Comment: I'm using a carousel like this: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/wByaqj. The number of slides in `<div class="carousel carousel-nav">` will be different each time and defined by admin within WordPress. Flickity uses absolute positioning, so I can't use flexbox to control the layout. This is why I need to calculate the elements by 100 to then apply the answer to an inline style. E.g. `<a style="width: 20%">`. Flexbox can be used within each slide itself, but not on the immediate children.

Comment: with flexbox you can assign an equal width to all the elements

Comment: Can't use flexbox in this case, see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has a function that you can use to count the number of occurances.
You can then simply divide them by 100.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a").length / 100;
```

For a PHP approach you can use `substr_count();`

```
<?php

$html = '
<nav class="tab-nav">           
  <a>Item One</a>
  <a>Item Two</a>
  <a>Item Three</a>
  <a>Item Four</a>
  <a>Item Five</a>
</nav>
';

echo $count = substr_count($html, "<a>") / 100;
```

Comment: nice one :) will rm my comment^ :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this `DOMDocument`. But it doesn't support `HTML-5`. You just need to stop the error displaying to disable the warnings

```
<?php
$html='
<nav class="tab-nav">           
  <a>Item One</a>
  <a>Item Two</a>
  <a>Item Three</a>
  <a>Item Four</a>
  <a>Item Five</a>
</nav>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$anchor_elements =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->length;

echo $anchor_elements/100;

?>
```

For javascript you just need this

```
var anchorlist = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length;
var anchor_length_divided_by_hundred = anchorlist/100;
console.log(anchor_length_divided_by_hundred);(function() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {

        elems[i].style.width = anchor_length_divided_by_hundred + "%";
}
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the JS version. Could you show an example of this adding a style? E.g. 100 / 5 = 20. `<a style="width: 20%">`